# CSS opacity animation don't work

Tags: css, animation, opacity

I want to animate opacity from 0 to 1 so it show fade out to white animation, First I've used before pseudo element but it didn't work so I replaced it with div but got the same results here is the code:

```css
body { 
    background: black;
}
.tv {
    height: 100vh;
    position: relative;
}
.white {
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    background: white;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    /* infinite while debugging */
    animation: opacity 5s ease-out infinite;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@keyframes opacity {
    0%: { opacity: 0 }
    100%: { opacity: 1; }
}
```

```html
<div class="tv">
   <div class="white"></div>
</div>
```

My first keyframe was like this:

```
@keyframes opacity {
    to: { opacity: 1; }
}
```

What's wrong with this animation?

Comment: Maybe you should change the name of the keyframes, `opacity` might cause conflicts. Check for any conflict in the console

Comment: @Vivick changed it to x and got the same results, no animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove colons after `0%` and `100%` and you will get the animation. Try like this:

```
@keyframes opacity {
    0% { opacity: 0 }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
```